# Retrieving variables for a Relay query fragment from an external store

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, react-router-relay, react-relay

When writing a GraphQL query fragment as part of a `RelayContainer`, I've been struggling with how to set query variables in certain situations. The basics outlined in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#initialvariables) are simple enough. But given the static nature of these queries and how a `RelayContainer` is a higher-order React Component, I'm not sure the best way to handle this when the input needed for a query is an object from an external source such as a Redux store. I don't have any way to retrieve data from that store before the component loads, so as a workaround I've been using the `@include` directive and setting a ready variable to true after the component loads:

```
class ListData extends React.Component {

  // ... proptypes 

  componentWillMount() {
    const { listDataInfo } = this.context.store.getState(); // Retrieve from Redux store

    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      input: {
        id: listDataInfo.id,
        user: listDataInfo.user
      },
      inputReady: true,
    });

    // The query will now execute and fetch all the data
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {/* view */}
    )
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(ListData, {
  initialVariables: {
    input: null,
    inputReady: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    listData: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on ListDataQuery {
        listData(input: $input) @include(if: $inputReady) {
          city
          state
          zip
          phone
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

In the end this works as expected, but I'm concerned that this is more of a hack, and that I'm missing something important with how Relay should be handling query variables. Is there a better way to do this? The [prepareVariables](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#preparevariables) looked like it could be useful but I still wouldn't have access to my data store. Here are my apparent options:

1. Keep it as is
2. Convert it to a mutation that will execute in a component lifecycle method. I'd rather not do this as it removes the data binding to the component.
3. Use a custom `RelayNetworkLayer` (which has access to my store) to intercept my queries and set the variables from an external store there. This also feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fdecampredon/f337605e393a5b032b85) that accomplishes exactly what I'm looking for. It lets you pass in redux state variables via `@container` decorator with the property `variablesFromState`. Essentially it will return either a standard Relay Container (if `variablesFromState` is not set) or a Relay Container wrapped in a redux `Provider` wrapper with the redux store instance passed in.